# Hi, I'm working on a google apps script in order to display in a spreadsheet all events from a google calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm working on a google apps script in order to display in a spread sheet all events from a google calendar in a certain time-range. I only have acces to the clientEmail, key and calendarEmail.
I found a solution to get the calendar using CalendarApp.getCalendarById(), but it doesn't really help me because I don't have the calendar ID. I only have acces to the clientEmail, key and calendarEmail. I tried using the OAuth2 authentication method:

I tried to connect to the Google Calendar using clientEmail and calendarEmail as calendarId for the method getCalendarById in CalendarApp class (CalendarApp.getCalendarById("CALENDAR_ID")), but I was receiving a null response.
Another authentication method I used was the OAuth2, also with no success. This call returns me an error "Exception: Invalid argument: key". I need to mention that the key is a token with 2200 characters.

```
OAuth2.createService("calendar")
    .setTokenUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")
    .setPrivateKey(key)
    .setIssuer(email)
    .setSubject(subject)
    .setScope(scopes);
```

In this code example the email is the clientEmail, the key is the private connection key, subject is the calendarEmail and the scopes is an array with an url to google apis ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"].

Is there a way to connect to google calendar with the information that I have, or it is mandatory to have that calendarId?

Comment: Consult with your admin

Comment: Its real easy if they share the calendar with you.